# Nativescript IOS ActionBar not showing background color until i scroll

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

With the latest IOS15 update my actionbar in the app doesn't display the blue background like I want to until you scroll down and it slowly comes into color as you scroll.

From this link https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420 It appears that in IOS15 the background is transparent by default.

How can I change this so that the background color stays at all times?
I tried the solution in the forum, but I cannot get UINavigationBarAppearance from my nativescript app. Updating to the latest nativescript version is a nightmare, so is there a way i can fix this with the versions i have in my package json below?

Actionbar in one of my pages(but it happens on all actionbars)

```
<ActionBar title="Report">    
<NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
<StackLayout >
    <Label [text]="report.Title"></Label>
    <Label [text]=' filter + "&#9660;"' (tap)="changeReportFilter()"></Label>
</StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

And i have a css property on this

```
ActionBar {
  background-color: $ab-background;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  
  Label{
    font-size: 12;
  }
}
```

package json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.10",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "~1.3.0",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "5.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.10",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trial and error I was able to fix it in my codebase. Here's what I did:

```
let navigationBar = Frame.topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
let appearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = new Color('#ff0000').iOS;
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance;
```

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: @phenric I have it in my dashboard.component.tns.ts file which is the landing page of my application after login, within my ngOnInit() lifecycle hook. You should be able to put it in any component that has an action bar.

Comment: Thank you @HackermanJS; it works! During this time, did you find a more global fix?

Comment: Glad it works @phenric! So interestingly enough this was a global fix for me, I assume because this is a root level navigation for me. So maybe if you put it on your base component that you navigate from it should work for you as well.

Comment: Thx bro it works! I put it in the first component of my sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone dealing with navigation bar color issues like I was,
This is what I am using to 1) add color back to the navigation bar in iOS 15+ and 2) address the default dark text color to, in my case, white.

Also this solution for NavtiveScript Vue v 6.x.x

Thanks @David for the titleTextAttributes piece! You rock

```
 if (isIOS) {
  console.log("IS iOS");
  let navigationBar = Frame.topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
  let appearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance;
  appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground();
  appearance.backgroundColor = new Color("blue").ios;
 appearance.titleTextAttributes = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary({
  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: UIColor.whiteColor
});
  navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
  navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance;
}
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error on `appearance.titleTextAttributes = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary({
        [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: UIColor.whiteColor
      });` Argument of type '{ [x: string]: UIColor; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NSDictionary<unknown, unknown>'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: UIColor; }' is missing the following properties from type 'NSDictionary<unknown, unknown>': allKeys, allValues, count, descriptionInStringsFileFormat

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use in a NativeScript 6.8 JavaScript project in the NavigatingTo event handler:

```
 // Handle transparent title bar in IOS 15 
  let osVersionMajor = platform.device.osVersion.split(".")[0];
  if (platform.isIOS && osVersionMajor >= 15 && global.viewModelCount < 2) {
    let navigationBar = Frame.topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
    let appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground();
    appearance.backgroundColor = new Color("#FF2525FE").ios;
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary({
      [NSForegroundColorAttributeName]: UIColor.whiteColor
    });
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance;
  }
```

The global.viewModelCount check prevents the code from running every time the main page is navigated to.

Comment: It cannot find name UINavigationBarAppearance. What library/version is that object in?